# Arabic Text displaying Problems

Tags: android

I am getting the problem while displaying arabic text in my android device

the require text is shown below

[image]

i am getting the different text like this

[image]

I am using the following code for this

my text is this :

`category_arabic[3] = "محـامـون"`  ;

`Typeface tfarsi1 = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this)`;

```
((TextView) pageView
                    .findViewById(R.id.menu_txtAttorneyLegalServices_ar))
                    .setTypeface(tfarsi1 );

((TextView) pageView
                    .findViewById(R.id.menu_txtAutoRepairSmog_ar))
                    .setText(Farsi.Convert(category_arabic[3]));
```

Please give me some solution for this problem. what i have to do for this ? i also used the `ArabicUtilities.java` file for this solution but not get the proper solution

Comment: Is this just that the output is in a different typeface? If so, you'll have to choose a typeface that matches your desired output more closely. Do you know what the original one is?

Comment: i didnt get the proper result. but I replace one single arabic word by arabic text image.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ArabicUtilities.java and reshape your text with "reshaper" function. for example:

```
textView1.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape("نمايش"));
```

Comment: i didnt get the proper result. but I replace one single arabic word by arabic text image.

Comment: if your device has Arabic setting you should not use reshape function. without this function you can see Arabic text very well.